# Direction Finder using directional antenna, digital signals amid clutter

Tags: digital-modes, mobile, direction-finding, hackrf

There are several methods for implementing direction finder.

1.
One of the method is by using directional antenna pointing to target device, and reading the received signal strength from the target device. This method also need the device to keep transmitting,
The following "direction finder" use such simple directional antenna and is described here:
http://www.pki-electronic.com/products/interception-and-monitoring-systems/gsm-direction-finder/

Yet, if this is the method that is used with the pki device, I wander how it can discern the device among other devices, because as I understand, the uplink frequency is shared among several devices nearby.

2.
There are other method too, using Pseudo-doppler DF method, such as done by Balint Seeber:
http://wiki.spench.net/wiki/SDRDF
But I see that the demonstration is done on VHF (not GSM/LTE)

I would like to ask:

- How does the first method (directional antenna) can find a device among other with same frequency ?
- Can the 2nd method (SDRDF) be used to locate GSM-frequency mobile device ? and discern a device among several with same frequency ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered using loop antennas?  The nulls on each side are much sharper than any peaks you will find with directional antennas.  But they need to rotate like any directional antenna, and they are bidirectional unless you use them with a shied on one side.

Comment: Does it help solving the base problem of multiple devices using the same uplink frequency ? Thx

Comment: Lots of variables involved before that can be answered.  Like is the target signal ID-able?  If so, then you can find the direction where it disappears using a loop.  Also, how far apart are all the other signals?  If they are all in a tight cluster then the problem is moot, I suppose.  In any case, the null of a loop is much sharper than either directional antennas or TOA (time-of-arrival) like the police use on their cars (with 4 antennas) to find money packs - They only get an 8-direction display.

Comment: Here is a link where we discuss finding hidden voice transmitters.  We were all on the same frequency but we knew the voice of our quarry.  We played it as a game:  https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/how-to-make-a-youre-getting-warm-cold-fox-hunting-game-based-on-rf-signals/7072

Comment: btw, it used to be an actual government secret that every transmitter is unique.  The FCC called it TXID.  They all exhibit a unique "fingerprint" of ramp-up amplitude and frequency wandering as they begin transmitting.  I suppose with a little digital signal processing it should be possible with the technology available to amateurs today.  But it would be a non-trivial project.  And yes, anything that works on VHF should be very similar on UHF.

Comment: @SDsolar, As I understand from your comments, the problem of "near" target with same frequency is still a problem whether we use loop, directional antenna, or multiple antenna. The only advantage of one antenna (and algorithm probably) on the other, is that it gives more accurate suspect points ?

Comment: @ransh, sorry, your GSM-related question is about a specific radio technology that is **not** amateur radio, and hence is off-topic here; SDSolar and the others will help you answer it in a general manner. But for GSM-specific direction finding: I think you're answering your own question. With purely directive-antenna power detection, no, you can't tell different handsets apart; you already know (and [have been told](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40412/how-does-direction-finding-work-when-using-gms-mobile-station-and-additional-han)) that.

Comment: So, the other question "can it be done": yes, "how can it be done for GSM": Off-topic here.

Comment: @ransh, you are correct about near targets.  So we put trimmer caps at the top of the loop so we can detune it as we get closer. and you are right that there is a significant advantage to getting more accurate directional cues.

Comment: @Marcus is right.  +1x2  This is a fun discussion, but we can't really answer your question as asked.  Note the lack of answers.

Comment: Understood, I mistakenly thought that GSM is included in Amateur radio. Thanks for pointing me this.